# Implement custom ads

Tags: android, admob

I'll soon publish my android application but I would like to monetize it with banners. However, I don't like the basics banners. I saw on Textra a good implementation of this banner.

I have to questions:

How can I do this type of banner ?
Do I have to use Google AdMob or I can use an other service

Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Its best if you keep on using services that are already provided, building your custom ad banner is a great idea but they are many factors to look at, such as possible attacks that they link may lead to and targeting advertisers may also be a problem if your user base isn't set well.

but this may be an ideal solution to your problem.

**Android**

1. *Create a custom webview layout that you will use for ad banner*
2. *Make sure its on all sizes required by android*
3. *include the layout of the custom webview within the custom listview you will be using*
4. *You can now load code/ad when present directly into that webview from your link*
5. Add custom listeners within your Android code to check whether the webview was click
6. Send this data back to your server (You may need it for advertiser)
7. Most importantly please hide the webview and display it only when data is present.

**Url**

1. *create a html/php or nodes web script that manipulates the availability of your ads from the server*
2. *implement methods you can use to listen for clicks within the page*

I will create a full tutorial on how you can do this, please check out my GitHub for the source code soon:

https://github.com/MLucien

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's an excellent idea, however (that was my second question), does Google allows to use other services than Google AdMobs or is it illegal ?

Comment: Not it is not illegal, unless if you will be providing content that will be illegal then that will be another issue.